# Oracle sql to print generic pattern

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write generic query to print the below pattern.
How can this be achieved?

```
 *****
 ****
 ***
 **
 *
```

Comment: `How can this be achieved?` ... by writing SQL code.  That being said, can you include your current SQL code in the question?

Comment: "Generic" how? What does that mean? Also, in the title you say "generic pattern" but in the question you say "generic query" - please clarify which one must be "generic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably looking for something like this. Note that the query includes two bind variables: `ch` for the character used (in your example, asterisk) and `n` for the starting length (in your example, 5).

In SQL*Plus, which I used for this illustrations, you declare the variables with the `variable` command, and you assign values to them in an anonymous PL/SQL block. In other interfaces (SQL Developer, Toad, etc.), the specific way to assign values to bind variables may be different.

The output is a single row, consisting of a single string; that string is text in multiple lines.

```
SQL> variable ch char(1)
SQL> variable n  number
SQL> exec :ch := '*'; :n := 5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


SQL> select  listagg(rpad(:ch, :n + 1 - level, :ch), chr(10))
  2             within group (order by level) as pattern
  3  from    dual
  4  connect by level <= :n;



PATTERN
----------
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

to generate 5 rows:

> | LEVEL |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 2 |
> | 3 |
> | 4 |
> | 5 |

You can use `RPAD('*', 4, '*')` to pad a string with `*` characters to a length of 4 characters `****`.

You can then combine the two and reverse the ordering (either with an `ORDER BY` clause or using mathematics).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f46e06f5b2900c1b5cbb12ea3afa6eac)*

---

Since this appears to be a homework question, I'll leave actually putting all the component parts together into a single query to you.